# Why don't I get all the fields that I have declared in my calendar view?

Tags: xml, calendar, odoo, field

I am trying to create a calendar view in Odoo, but I didn't get exactly what I want. So, for that, I have tried this code.

```
 <record id="view_planfication_rotation_calendar" model="ir.ui.view">
         <field name="name">planification.rotation.calendar</field>
         <field name="model">plannification.rotation</field>
         <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <calendar string="Planification" date_start="date_sortie" color="states">
                    <field name="states" invisible="1" filters="1"/>
                    <field name="client" invisible="1"/>
                </calendar>
         </field>
     </record>
```

i was expecting to see in my calendar view the both fields : states and client but it returns the states only.

can you please help me ?!

Comment: Why did you put `invisible="1"` on the fields?

Comment: I have watched many videos on creating a calendar view, and they all used the attribute "invisible" with a value of "1". I also asked the same question, and when I tried it with the "states" field, it worked, and the "states" field was visible in my calendar view. Therefore, I don't think that is the reason why the other fields are invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields that you put as part of the calendar view are fields shown on the Popup Calendar Card when you click on the Calendar Event without open the full form view. If you put it as invisible you will get those fields invisible in the Calendar Card

Comment: @aekis.devThank you for your reply. Your answer was helpful. I still have a question: How can I display fields in my calendar view? Could you please provide guidance on this matter?

Comment: I think you wanna put more information than the Calendar Event title... for that you will need to customize the Calendar Components since default Odoo doesn't let you show more data